# Partition Strategy for applying multiple JOINs on a Flink DataSet

Tags: java, join, apache-flink

I am using `Flink 1.4.0`.

Suppose I have a `POJO` as follows:

```
public class Rating {
    public String name;
    public String labelA;
    public String labelB;
    public String labelC;
    ...        
}
```

and a `JOIN` function:

```
public class SetLabelA implements JoinFunction<Tuple2<String, Rating>, Tuple2<String, String>, Tuple2<String, Rating>> {

    @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Rating> join(Tuple2<String, Rating> rating, Tuple2<String, String> labelA) {
        rating.f1.setLabelA(labelA)
        return rating;
    }
}
```

and suppose I want to apply a `JOIN` operation to set the values of each field in a `DataSet<Tuple2<String, Rating>>`, which I can do as follows:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Rating>> ratings = // [...]
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Double>> aLabels = // [...]
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Double>> bLabels = // [...]
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Double>> cLabels = // [...]
...
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Rating>>
            newRatings =
            ratings.leftOuterJoin(aLabels, JoinOperatorBase.JoinHint.REPARTITION_SORT_MERGE)

                   // key of the first input
                   .where("f0")

                   // key of the second input
                   .equalTo("f0")

                   // applying the JoinFunction on joining pairs
                   .with(new SetLabelA());
```

Unfortunately, this is necessary as both ratings and all `xLabels` are very big `DataSets` and I am forced to look into each of the `xlabels` to find the field values I require, while at the same time it is not the case that all rating keys exist in each `xlabels`.

This practically means that I have to perform a `leftOuterJoin` per `xlabel`, for which I need to also create the respective `JoinFunction` implementation that utilises the correct setter from the `Rating` `POJO`.

Is there a more efficient way to solve this that anyone can think of?

As far as the partitioning strategy goes, I have made sure to sort the `DataSet<Tuple2<String, Rating>> ratings` with:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Rating>> sorted_ratings = ratings.sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING).setParallelism(1);
```

By setting parallelism to 1 I can be sure that the whole dataset will be ordered. I then use `.partitionByRange`:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Rating>> partitioned_ratings = sorted_ratings.partitionByRange(0).setParallelism(N);
```

where `N` is the number of cores I have on my VM. Another side question I have here is whether the first `.setParallelism` which is set to 1 is restrictive in terms of how the rest of the pipeline is executed, i.e. can the follow up `.setParallelism(N)` change how the `DataSet` is processed?

Finally, I did all these so that when `partitioned_ratings` is joined with a `xlabels` `DataSet`, the JOIN operation will be done with `JoinOperatorBase.JoinHint.REPARTITION_SORT_MERGE`. According to `Flink` docs for `v.1.4.0`:

> REPARTITION_SORT_MERGE: The system partitions (shuffles) each input (unless the input is already partitioned) and sorts each input (unless it is already sorted). The inputs are joined by a streamed merge of the sorted inputs. This strategy is good if one or both of the inputs are already sorted.

So in my case, `ratings` is sorted (I think) and each of the `xlabels` `DataSets` are not, hence it makes sense that this is the most efficient strategy. Anything wrong with this? Any alternative approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I haven't been able to pull through this strategy. It seems like relying on `JOINs` is too troublesome as they are expensive operations and one should avoid them unless they are really necessary.

For instance, `JOINs` should be used if both `Datasets` are very big in size. If they are not, a convenient alternative is the use of `BroadCastVariables` by which one of the two `Datasets` (the smallest), is broadcasted across workers for whatever purpose it is used. A example appears below (copied from this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Variables+Closures+vs.+Broadcast+Variables) for convenience)

```
DataSet<Point> points = env.readCsv(...);

DataSet<Centroid> centroids = ... ; // some computation

points.map(new RichMapFunction<Point, Integer>() {

    private List<Centroid> centroids;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        this.centroids = getRuntimeContext().getBroadcastVariable("centroids");
    }

    @Override
    public Integer map(Point p) {
        return selectCentroid(centroids, p);
    }

}).withBroadcastSet("centroids", centroids);
```

Also, since populating fields of a POJO implies that a quite similar code will be leverage repeatedly, one should definitely use [`jlens`](https://github.com/ppetr/jLens) to avoid code repetition and write a more concise and easy to follow solution.